# Android device processing 16 bit per sample image

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to load a 16 bit per channel (48 bit per pixel) RGB image into Bitmap in Android.
So its, 16 bit per channel with three channels.

When I do this with 8 bit per sample(24 bit per pixel) RGB it works fine. I do it like this:

```
int bitPerSample = 8;
byte [] 8bitPerSampleRGBsource = myOwngetRGBByteArrayFromFileFunctions(File, bitPerSample);

Mat m = new Mat(imageWidth,imageHeight,CvType.CV_8UC3);
m.put(0,0, rgb);

Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(m.cols(), m.rows(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);      
Utils.matToBitmap(m, bm);
```

Now this works fine but I want to use CvType.CV_16UC3 instead.16 bit with three channels(48 bit)

The problem is that ARGB8888 is 32 bit integer(8+8+8+8) but I need 48 bit integer.

No support for 48 bit bitmaps in Android?

Any workaround for this problem? Is this limited in Android due to lack of processor power?

Best regards

Comment: "it doesn't work" isn't a clear problem statement

Comment: [This](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html) tells you what's available. `ARGB_8888` clearly isn't 48-bit image data. What led you to think this *should* work?

Comment: So 32-bit integer image data is the best Android can provide? No way to go around this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I can answer this now. Android only supports 32-bit RGBA bitmaps.